# Android Studio Icon for Button does not fit

Tags: android, android-studio, button, icons

My Icon(size 256*256) does not fit into size of button, it is center aligned and so small  Button appearing as this [image] and anyone make my button fit to its original size of button and appear as Required icon for button
[image: ]].

Changing size of icon makes icons go out of bound of the button size, kindly help me to get rid of it.

My code is

```
<br.com.bloder.magic.view.MagicButton

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:magic_button_size="50dp"
    app:button_icon="@drawable/three"
    app:button_icon_width="35dp"
    app:button_icon_height="35dp"
    app:hide_text="EigthSemester"
    app:icon_button_color="#ced0d4"
    app:expandable_area_color="#2f83de"/>
```

Comment: can you provide the layout xml ?

Comment: are you using any third party library for this button ? or is this a standard android Button view?

Comment: Edited my post kindly see to it

Comment: Third party library

Comment: 'com.github.bloder:magic:1.1'

Comment: Ref: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3988

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the library and it seems like the size of icon "magic_button_size" and "button_icon_width" "button_icon_height" are connected. These should be exact 50% of magic_button_size.That's the reason why the icon is not in center.

Try changing the xml to :

```
   <br.com.bloder.magic.view.MagicButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    app:magic_button_size="50dp"
    app:button_icon="@drawable/three"
    app:button_icon_width="25dp"
    app:button_icon_height="25dp"
    app:hide_text="EigthSemester"
    app:icon_button_color="#ced0d4"
    app:expandable_area_color="#2f83de"/>
```

Comment: Is their any way to change that linking from 50% to 100% , If you can do it it will be a great  help for me.